# Memory still used after process exits

Tags: linux, admin, administration

I have a question about a weird occurrence, I am on a server with 1GB ram, I run only a single application that is lightweight, after a while its memory usage increases (probably a memory leak I did not find yet), but that's another story, the problem is, when it gets too much memory used I exit the process, to my surprise the memory usage is still high, how could that be? The memory is not cached, it is "raw" memory being used, but htop does not seem to know which process is using it either ...

Here I attach the image so you can see it, it is sorted by Memory usage descending.
I don't understand how memory usage is 751MB if the process that uses the most memory is using 1.8%.
I have read some solutions such as disabling swap, but swap is disabled as seen in the image.

[image]

### Update 1

Here I attach the meminfo:

```
MemTotal:        1004852 kB
MemFree:          108456 kB
MemAvailable:      97392 kB
Buffers:            2768 kB
Cached:            31868 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           503268 kB
Inactive:          15100 kB
Active(anon):     491920 kB
Inactive(anon):     2852 kB
Active(file):      11348 kB
Inactive(file):    12248 kB
Unevictable:       18516 kB
Mlocked:           18516 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                20 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        502288 kB
Mapped:            28200 kB
Shmem:              2856 kB
KReclaimable:      96860 kB
Slab:             308536 kB
SReclaimable:      96860 kB
SUnreclaim:       211676 kB
KernelStack:        5676 kB
PageTables:        11836 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      502424 kB
Committed_AS:     808208 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       12656 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             1772 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      501740 kB
DirectMap2M:      546816 kB
```

There is an interesting solution about freeing cached memory on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524846/why-does-my-system-use-more-ram-after-an-hour-of-usage but here it does not work, the problem is not the cached memory ...

### Update 2

Someone I know told me that was weird to have that many sshd processes, I gave it a try killing all those root@notty sshd processes and it worked. Problem solved, I leave this question here hoping it may be useful for others.

Comment: Maybe it’s a kernel thread. Set htop to show them. You can find out how here: https://superuser.com/a/1322288

Answer (score 0):

Someone I know told me that was weird to have that many sshd processes, I gave it a try killing all those root@notty sshd processes and it worked. Problem solved, I leave this question here hoping it may be useful for others.
To simplify the process I used the following Golang Code:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3/process"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    processes, err := process.Processes()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    sshCount := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(processes); i++ {
        currentProcess := processes[i]
        name, err := currentProcess.Name()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to retrieve the name of process %d\n", currentProcess.Pid)
            continue
        }

        // username, err := currentProcess.Username()
        cmdLine, err := currentProcess.Cmdline()
        // cwd, _ := currentProcess.Cwd()
        // terminalStr, _ := currentProcess.Terminal()

        if strings.Contains(name, "sshd") && cmdLine == "sshd: root@notty" {
            sshCount++
            err = currentProcess.Terminate()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error on terminating %d %s\n", currentProcess.Pid, name)
                err = currentProcess.Kill()
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Error on Killing %d %s\n", currentProcess.Pid, name)
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("Killed %d %s\n", currentProcess.Pid, name)
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Terminated successfully %d %s\n", currentProcess.Pid, name)
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("We got %d sshd processes\n", sshCount)
}
```